# PUT request works in Postman but not a deno typescript file as a fetch request

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, put, deno

I can do a put request just fine in Postman.
[image]

But when I try to do the same put request in a deno fresh app through a fetch command like this:

```
async function sendSignature() {
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const nonce = "asdf123492fd";
        const signatureSigned = await signer.signMessage(nonce);
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          });
        const opts = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                key: props.singleUser,
                wallet_address: walletAddrs,
                signature: signatureSigned
          })
        }
        console.log(opts.body);
        const rawPosts = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/kythis1', opts);
        console.log(rawPosts);
    }
```

Btw all of the values are being populated in `body`. I can confirm that `key`, `wallet_address`, and `signature` are not null and are strings. It fails though... Here's what the browser's console looks like.
[image]

This is the entry point for the backend oak (deno's version of express) server.

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { APP_HOST, APP_PORT } from "./config.js";
import router from "./routes.js";
import _404 from "./controllers/404.js";
import errorHandler from "./controllers/errorHandler.js";
import { oakCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use(oakCors()); // Enable CORS for All Routes
app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(_404);

console.log(`Listening on port:${APP_PORT}...`);

await app.listen(`${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT}`);
```

This is the function that is getting called by the put request:

```
import User from "../db/database.js";

export default async ({ request, response }) => {
  if (!request.hasBody) {
    response.status = 400;
    response.body = { msg: "Invalid user data" };
    return;
  }

  const body = request.body();
  const {
    key, wallet_address, signature
  } = JSON.parse(await body.value);

  console.log(signature);

  if (!key) {
    response.status = 422;
    response.body = { msg: "Incorrect user data. Email and key are required" };
    return;
  }

  const foundUser = await User.where('key', '=', key).first();
  if (!foundUser) {
    response.status = 404;
    response.body = { msg: `User with key ${key} not found` };
    return;
  }
  foundUser.wallet_address = wallet_address;
  foundUser.updated_at = new Date();
  const updatedResp = await foundUser.update();

  response.body = { msg: "User updated", updatedResp };
};
```

Finally this is the backend routes:

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

import getUsers from "./controllers/getUsers.js";
import getUserDetails from "./controllers/getUserDetails.js";
import createUser from "./controllers/createUser.js";
import updateUser from "./controllers/updateUser.js";
//import deleteUser from "./controllers/deleteUser.js";

const router = new Router();

router
  .get("/users", getUsers)
  .get("/users/:key", getUserDetails)
  .post("/users", createUser)
  .put("/users/:key", updateUser);
  
  //.delete("/users/:id", deleteUser);

export default router;
```

So why can I successfully call this function with a Postman put request, but I can't do a successful put request with fetch through a typescript file?

Comment: Error 500 usually outputs some additional data in the backend terminal. Have you tried to check if `body.value` has the correct value on the backend?

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting any backend logs. Is there any way to force more detailed logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postman and fetch call aren't exactly the same.
Looking at postman it has 8 headers, and content-type seems to be set on Text.
While the fetch() is set on application/json.

When content type is application/json your request.body() is likely already parsed. Thus another JSON.parse will throw an error.
One easy fix with your current code would be to set your javascript headers to this:

```
const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
          });
```

This will avoid 2 times parsing of the json file.

But the better fix would be to actually use application/json and see/log what request.body() returns.

Answer (score 0):

Postman simply doesn’t care about CORS headers. So CORS is just a browser concept and not a strong security mechanism. It allows you to restrict which other web apps may use your backend resources.

You have to just specifies CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) headers.